# Using Maclaurin series to study the convergence of $\sum \limits _{k=1}^\infty (1- \cos\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that the series $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty (1- \cos\frac{1}{n})$ converges.

One way is to use trigonometric identity which says $(1- \cos\frac{1}{n})$ = $2\sin^2(\frac{1}{2n})$ and from here I need to show that $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty 2 \left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2 $ converges, which is pretty simple because the denominator's $n^p$ and $ p > 1 $.

**But I want to try another approach**. I know that the beginning of $\sin(\frac{1}{n})$ Maclaurin series is ($x_0 = 0$)$ 1 - (\frac{1}{n})^2 \ 2! $. which means I need to check: $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty (1- (1 - (\frac{1}{n})^2 \ 2!))$ = $\sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n})^2 \ 2!$  and this is clearly converges because it is harmonic sequence where $n^p$ and $ p > 1 $.

Does it make sense what I just wrote?

> **What I struggle with: Is my Maclaurin evaluation true?**

Comment: It is "Maclaurin".

Comment: I rewrote the question to make it more clear what is actually asked. Writing a question as "Does this series converge?.... Well I already know this, so now I have a different question" is a bad idea.

Comment: ... and then you accept as a duplicate a question that actually isn't. Oh well.

Comment: Also, be careful with indices in the summation. They are not decoration.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument does not seem entirely waterproof for a general analytic function but you can use the linear approximation in a different way by noting that $\sin x<x$ for $x>0.$ Or, if you want to stick to the original cosine, $\cos x>1-x^2/2.$